# how to override default hazlecast.xml configuration?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, hazelcast

Recently integrated Hazelcast in my existing spring mvc project. i want to disable multicast autodiscovery mechanism and want it through ip address. done the required changes in Hazelcast.xml and put it under resources i.e WEB-INF/classes but configuration not override.default configuration is active and multicast discovery mode not getting disabled. so let me know how to disable multicast discovery in spring mvc project?

Comment: How have you named the file ? Your text suggests both `hazlecast.xml` and `Hazelcast.xml`, but the file name  that will be searched for is `hazelcast.xml`.

Comment: hazelcast.xml i have used this one

Comment: After the build, what does `find . -name hazelcast.xml` show ? Can you also post start-up logs ?

Answer (score 1):

If `hazelcast.xml` is on your classpath it should be automatically applied. You can check [Hazelcast Reference Manual: Checking Configuration](https://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/latest/manual/html-single/#checking-configuration).

If it does not work for you, you can always:

- explicitly define the configuration location with `-Dhazelcast.config=<path-to-config>`
- use [programmatic configuration](https://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/latest/manual/html-single/#configuring-programmatically)

If nothing works for you, then please share a minimal sample project to reproduce the issue.